# Fail to upload files from AngularJS to ExpressJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I am now using angular-file-upload packages to upload files. After I press item.upload(), it claims to be successfully uploaded the file, but I see the req.body is empty. Please Help!

Here is the angular code to handle it:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = $fileUploader.create({
        scope: $scope,                          // to automatically update the html. Default: $rootScope
    url: '/api/teams/upload',
    formData: [
        { key: 'value' }
    ],
    filters: [
        function (item) {                    // first user filter
            $scope.previewImage(item);
            return true;
        }
    ]
});
```

And here is the way to trigger the upload:

```
uploader.bind('afteraddingfile', function (event, item) {
    // console.info(item.file);
    console.info('After adding a file', item);

    // console.log('item.upload();');
    item.upload();
});
```

And finally here is the express js code:

```
exports.upload = function(req, res) {
// console.log('req.headers');
// console.log(req.headers);

console.log('req.body');
console.log(req.body);
```

What wrong's with it?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your POST is encoded as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`....

In Express 4  you need to set the `body parser` in your server:

```
var bodyParser     = require('dy-parser');
//...

var app            = express();
//...
app.use(bodyParser());  // pull information from html in POST

var busboy = require('connect-busboy');    
app.use(busboy());
```

In earlier version of Express you only needed to add the body parser from the framework itself and files will be store on the configured location:

```
     app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '10mb', uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/uploads' }));               // pull information from html in POST
```

Since version 4 removed support for connect now you need to add your custom support for multipart/form data  to parser  multi/part POSTs, so you will have to to do something like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

//...
app.use(busboy()); 
//...
app.post('/api/teams/upload', function(req, res) {
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename); 
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/files/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.redirect('back');
        });
    });
});
```

On the client side you need to call the  `$upload.upload` To start the upload